# Assessing overall variation for each case in panel data

Tags: variance, panel-data

I have a panel data set - a score on a single measure for hundreds of people, taken once per day for all 365 days of a year. I'm looking for the best method to assess overall variation within each person's scores. In other words, I care about the overall frequency and magnitude of changes, not just the absolute change between Day 1 and Day 365.

It seems like simply the variance (or SD) for each individual would be a fairly decent indicator, but this doesn't seem to be used in panel data studies. Is there something better I should use?

I'll then use this (unknown) indicator as a DV in a regression, to see how different personal characteristics influence the degree of variation throughout the year.

Thanks!

Comment: I too think variance or SD should serve your need. why do you think variance or SD doesn't seem to be used in panel studies?

Comment: I'm just getting into panel data research and hadn't yet seen a study using SD.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the coefficient of variation which is defined as the ratio of the standard deviation to the mean. Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation